# Cómo deshabilitar el boton de submit si se cumple una condición

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito desactivar el botón de submit cuando el valor del campo Estado (id="fe696") sea "Contestado". El problema es que cuando lo escribo manualmente sí me funciona pero cuando viene el form con value="Contestado" por defecto, no aparece deshabilitado. Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias!

```html
<input name="Estado" id="fe696" value="Contestado" onkeyup="comprobar()"/>

<input  type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">

<script>
    function comprobar() {
        if (this.value != 'Contestado'){
            var Pagar = document.getElementById("fe583");
            Pagar.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ese es todo el código?

Comment: De momento sí @BetaM

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas pasar el atributo `this` a la funcion.  Algo asi:

```html
<input name="Estado" id="fe696" value="Contestado" onkeyup="comprobar(this)"/>

<input  type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">

<script>
    function comprobar(texto) {
        var Pagar = document.getElementById("fe583");
        if (texto.value != 'Contestado'){            
            Pagar.disabled = true;
        } else {
            Pagar.disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm no me funciona del todo bien, pues lo que busco es que cuando viene por defecto "Contestado" se deshabilite, no cuando tenga que escribirlo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes simplemente utilizar la función setAttribute()

```
Pagar.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

y en caso contrario para habilitarlo nuevamente podrías utilizar removeAttribute();

```
Pagar.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias, no me está funcionando... probablemente haya hecho algo mal. Me puede ayudar a saber en qué parte del codigo debo poner esto? Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, la solución de @alanfcm en la otra respuesta funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

en este caso se debe usar asi ---pagar.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");---
ya que los inputs de tipo submit no cuentan con condicion true o false para la propiedad disabled.